# Индекс находится вне границ массива при выборочной сортировке

Tags: pascal

Задачей сортировки является найти в массиве `min` и `max`, первый отправить влево, второй - вправо, и затем продолжить сортировать, не трогая крайние (поставленные) элементы.

Помогите разобраться с ошибкой: выводится только исходный массив, а дальше программа работает бесконечно.

Мой код:

```
const n=10;
var a:array[1..n] of integer;
i,j,max,min,c,flag:integer;
begin
  for i:=1 to n do begin
    a[i]:=random(1000);
    write(a[i],' ')
  end;
  j:=0;
  max:=-1;
  min:=1000;
  repeat
    flag:=1; j:=j+1;
    for j:=1 to n-1 do begin
      for i:=1 to n-j do begin
        if a[i]<min then a[i]:=min; 
        if a[i]>max then a[i]:=max;
      end;
        c:=a[i];a[i]:=min;min:=c;
        c:=a[n-j];a[n-j]:=max;max:=c;
        flag:=2;
    end;
  until flag=1;
  writeln;
  for i:=1 to n do write(a[i],' ')
end.
```

Comment: Что такое `min` и `max`? Почему вы их не меняете в цикле? Почему вы их используете в качестве индекса?

Comment: убрал min и max как индексы. команда должна пробегать по массиву и запоминать наибольший и наименьший элементы, с этим есть ошибка?

Comment: у вас три явных шага в задаче указано. решайте их отдельно. Сначала перебираете массив справа налево передвигая наименьший элемент. Затем перебираете массив с начала до конца, передвигая максимальный в конец.  Третьим шагом сортируете массив с 1 до n-1 элемента. Решите эти три вещи последовательно,а не одним циклом.

Comment: задача как раз в том, чтобы при каждом переборе сразу отбирать и переставлять min и max.